# Determine Click-thru Percentage With PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a small sponsorship application(PHP/MySql) for my personal blog, and am almost finish, but I am stuck on how to calculate the click-thru rate of my sponsors campaigns.

I was always terrible with working out percentages, so any practical help would be appreciated. The data is stored in the DB as simple numbers.. So as expected, when a page refreshes, or a sponsors ad is clicked, the data updates with an incrementation of 1.

So using these values...say $clicks and $impressions, how would I determine the click-thru rate? What would be the sum I would use to calculate? An example function would really be appreciated.

Kind Regards, Lea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is the percentage of `$impressions` that leads to `$clicks`. The ratio is found by calculating `$clicks/$impressions`, and then you can multiply by 100 to see the percentage.

As an example, if there are 100 impressions and 1 click, the ratio will be `1/100 = 0.01`, and the percentage will be `0.01 * 100 = 1%`.

Comment: Gee, it was so simple an answer. Thanks for taking the time to leave it!